# Symfony2 custom validator annotation not working

Tags: symfony

I have a custom validator in `src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Component/Validator/CurrentPasswordValidator.php`:

```
<?php
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface,
    JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Validator,
    JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams,
    JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;

/**
 * @Validator("user.validator.current_password")
 */
class CurrentPasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    // ...
}
```

And then I have this at `src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Component/Validator/Contraints/CurrentPassword.php`:

```
<?php
namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CurrentPassword extends Constraint
{
    public $message = "Your current password is not valid";

    /** 
     * @return string
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {   
        return 'user.validator.current_password';
    }   
}
```

For some reason, when I try to add an annotation that uses this validator, I get an error. Here's my entity/annotation:

```
<?php

namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable as JoinTable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn as JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MaxLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints\CurrentPassword;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @var string $password
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @CurrentPassword()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation
>   "@VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints\CurrentPassword"
>   in property VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User::$password does not exist,
>   or could not be auto-loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `VNN\PressboxBundle\VNNPressboxBundle()` is correctly registered with the kernel in `AppKernel.php`.

**Update:** If it is correctly registered, and `src/` is registered as a fallback with the autoloader (assuming `VNN/` is under `src/`), you may want to try and load the service yourself manually and check the stack trace if/when it fails:

```
$validator = $container->get('user.validator.current_password');
// Pretending this is a unit test:
// $this->assertInstanceOf('VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints\CurrentPasswordValidator', $validator);
```

Also, make sure you have cleared the cache (if not testing in `dev` environment).

---

Side note (but unrelated to your problem) - if you start to add more validators, it will be more useful to use this syntax:

```
<?php

namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity;

use VNN\PressboxBundle\Component\Validator\Constraints as VNN;

class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @VNN\CurrentPassword
     */
    private $password;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I checked and `VNNPressboxBundle` is properly registered.

Comment: @JasonSwett: Updated my answer with some other possibilities.